# Mostrar valor devuelto SQL Server en ventana de WPF C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Tengo el siguiente código con el cual recupero el valor que me retorna un procedimiento almacenado

```
public bool EjecutarSQL(string consecutivo, string otratabla)
    {
        Clsconexion objConexion = new Clsconexion();
        objConexion.SQL = "EXECUTE insertarDatos" + "'" + consecutivo + "'" + "," + "'" + otratabla + "'";
        objConexion.NombreTabla = "tconsecutivo";
        if (objConexion.LlenarDataSet(false) == true)
        {
            tblTablaDatos = objConexion.MiDataSet.Tables[0];
            if (tblTablaDatos.Rows.Count>0)//se encontraron datos
            {
                respuesta = tblTablaDatos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                objConexion.CerrarConexion();
                objConexion = null;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                tblTablaDatos = null;
                strerror = "No se encontraron datos, soy un error de capa dao";
                objConexion.CerrarConexion();
                objConexion = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strerror = objConexion.Error;
            objConexion.CerrarConexion();
            objConexion = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Que lo guardo en la variable **respuesta**, este fragmento lo tengo **en una capa de datos** como me puedo llevar esa variable hasta **la capa vista**. Para no realizar esta consulta en la vista si no retornarle a la vista solamente ese resultado.

Pd: este código es de pruebas, disculpen mis comentarios en el o los nombres poco profesionales.

Agradezco todos sus aportes

Comment: y si en lugar de devolver un bool devolves algo del tipo de respuesta? es eso, o tu procedimiento tiene un parametro out, pero lo otro parece mejor..  Esto lo veo mas como una desicion de diseño mas que un problema en si...

Comment: @gbianchi Son unas validaciones que hago en SQL donde consulto varias cosas y necesito capturar una de esas respuestas de SQL para concatenarla con otra respuesta que recupero ya desde c# pero como esa consulta es de otro proyecto por eso la hacemos en SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la palabra clave [out](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out) la cual modifica el parametro para permitirle pasar un argumento a un método mediante una referencia en lugar de un valor.

```
public bool EjecutarSQL(string consecutivo, string otratabla, out string respuesta)
{
    respuesta = string.Empty;
    Clsconexion objConexion = new Clsconexion();
    objConexion.SQL = "EXECUTE insertarDatos" + "'" + consecutivo + "'" + "," + "'" + otratabla + "'";
    objConexion.NombreTabla = "tconsecutivo";
    if (objConexion.LlenarDataSet(false) == true)
    {
        tblTablaDatos = objConexion.MiDataSet.Tables[0];
        if (tblTablaDatos.Rows.Count>0)//se encontraron datos
        {
            respuesta = tblTablaDatos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            objConexion.CerrarConexion();
            objConexion = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            tblTablaDatos = null;
            strerror = "No se encontraron datos, soy un error de capa dao";
            objConexion.CerrarConexion();
            objConexion = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strerror = objConexion.Error;
        objConexion.CerrarConexion();
        objConexion = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Y desde tu vista lo puedes llamar asi:

```
string respuesta;

bool flag = EjecutarSQL(consecutivo, otratabla, out respuesta);

// demas validaciones pertinentes
```

Comment: Perfecto me corrio tal cual, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Aunque ya obtuviste una respuesta, voy a agregar otra manera de hacerlo, que no implica usar variables de salida.

La idea es regresar mas de un valor en un método. Desde mi punto de vista los parámetros de un método es mejor dejarlos de entrada.

Para regresar mas de un valor en un método puedes utilizar el tipo tupla, que está definido en System.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
public Tuple<bool, string> EjecutarSQL(string consecutivo, string otratabla)
{
    var respuesta = string.Empty;
    var objConexion = new Clsconexion();
    objConexion.SQL = "EXECUTE insertarDatos" + "'" + consecutivo + "'" + "," + "'" + otratabla + "'";
    objConexion.NombreTabla = "tconsecutivo";

    if (objConexion.LlenarDataSet(false) == true)
    {
        tblTablaDatos = objConexion.MiDataSet.Tables[0];
        if (tblTablaDatos.Rows.Count > 0) 
        {
            respuesta = tblTablaDatos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            objConexion.CerrarConexion();
            objConexion = null;
            return Tuple.Create(true, respuesta);
        }
        else
        {
            tblTablaDatos = null;
            strerror = "No se encontraron datos, soy un error de capa dao";
            objConexion.CerrarConexion();
            objConexion = null;
            return Tuple.Create(false, respuesta);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strerror = objConexion.Error;
        objConexion.CerrarConexion();
        objConexion = null;
        return Tuple.Create(false, respuesta);
    }
}
```

Y para usarla:

```
var result = EjecutarSQL(consecutivo, otratabla);
if (result.Item1) // Item1 contiene el primer valor, el bool
{
    var respuesta = result.Item2; // Item2 tiene el segundo valor, el tipo string
    // resto del código
}
```

EDIT: Si usas Visual Studio 2017 tienes acceso a C# 7, por lo que puedes utilizar el nuevo tipo ValueTuple, el ejemplo anterior quedaría así con las ValueTuple:

```
public (bool, string) EjecutarSQL(string consecutivo, string otratabla)
{
    var respuesta = string.Empty;
    var objConexion = new Clsconexion();
    objConexion.SQL = "EXECUTE insertarDatos" + "'" + consecutivo + "'" + "," + "'" + otratabla + "'";
    objConexion.NombreTabla = "tconsecutivo";

    if (objConexion.LlenarDataSet(false) == true)
    {
        tblTablaDatos = objConexion.MiDataSet.Tables[0];
        if (tblTablaDatos.Rows.Count > 0) 
        {
            respuesta = tblTablaDatos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            objConexion.CerrarConexion();
            objConexion = null;
            return (true, respuesta);
        }
        else
        {
            tblTablaDatos = null;
            strerror = "No se encontraron datos, soy un error de capa dao";
            objConexion.CerrarConexion();
            objConexion = null;
            return (false, respuesta);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strerror = objConexion.Error;
        objConexion.CerrarConexion();
        objConexion = null;
        return (false, respuesta);
    }
}
```

Y se usa así:

```
(bool success, string respuesta) = EjecutarSQL(consecutivo, otratabla);
if (success)
{
    // aquí puedes usar la variable respuesta
    // resto del código
}
```